# Array in jquery retains old data even after ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of brands and categories. One brand can have multiple categories.

```html
{% for brand in brands %}
    <li><input type="radio" value="{{brand.title}}" name="brand">{{brand.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}

{% for category in categories %}
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="{{category.title}}" name="category" > {{category.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="brand_category">
```

```js
<script>
 var parameter = [];
  var brand = [];
  var category = [];

    $('#brand_category').click(function(event) {
        $("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
                category.push($(this).val())
            }
        });
        parameter.push({
            brand :   $("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
            category: category
        })
        var json = JSON.stringify(parameter);

        $.ajax({        
            type: "post",
            url: "{% url 'seller_details' %}",
            data: { 
                'parameter[]' : json , 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}'
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#loading-image').hide();
            },
            error: function(response, error) { }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I tried to send brand and category from the above script but it retains old data in the arrays brand, category and parameter. Is this the correct way to send data for the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're defining the `category` array outside of the click handler and you're not clearing it's values between clicks. Also note that the `if` statement in the `each` block is redundant as the selector is only retrieving elements which are checked.

To solve the issue you can either change the code so that the array is defined inside the handler:

```
$('#brand_category').click(function(event) {
    var category = [];
    $("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").each(function(){
        category.push($(this).val());
    });

    // rest of your code...
});
```

Alternatively you can generate the array from scratch on each click:

```
var category = [];
$('#brand_category').click(function(event) {
    category = $("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    // rest of your code...
});
```

Comment: And also Do i need to uncheck the checked checkboxes after ajax submit?

Comment: category array is created well ...but parameter array is till pushing old data